# post object file into server

Tags: php, angularjs

I'm currently uploading files in an array to server but its undefined in return. However, checking console log there is an object present. My problem how to post on server. Is there a proper way to do this so that i can process my file in a foreach loop in server. here is my code.

html

```
<td>
    <div class="requpload form-input">
        <div class="controls">
            <div class="normal-input">
                 <input type="file" ng-file-model="info.file[pIndex]">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

console log js

[image]

js

```
$scope.saveInfo = function(){  
           var form_data = new FormData();  
           angular.forEach($scope.info.file, function(file){  
                form_data.append('file', file);
           });  
           $http.post('data.php', form_data,  
           {  
                transformRequest: angular.identity,  
                headers: {'Content-Type': undefined,'Process-Data': false}  
           }).then(function(response){  

               console.log(response.data);

           });  
      }
```

server

```
$file = $_FILES['file']['name'];
   echo json_encode($file); //undefined in respone

   //how to implement here in foreach
```

Comment: If you want to use php's `$_FILES`, you must use `multipart/form-data` content type.

Comment: i wonder i used $_FILES in a single input not an array and its working. however, the situation is my input file is inside ng-repeat so its an array and that the problem its undefined in the server.

Comment: maybe my problem is on the server on how to post my file on array. even i used JSON.stringify on the js part but still undefined in the server.

Comment: @Rye you can try this `angular.forEach($scope.info.file,function(file){
     form_data.append('file[]',file);
   });` and check server side code also.

Comment: Thanks @Sanoj_V but i tried tha already its undefined file in the server.

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace code in `angular.forEach` like:

```
angular.forEach($scope.files, function(file){
    console.log(file);
    form_data.append('file[]', file);
});
```

Rest of angularjs code same as you posted. Now, In your server side code to handle single or multiple file.

```
foreach($_FILES['file']['name'] as $key=>$val){  //foreach for handle single or multiple file upload
    $upload_dir = "upload/";
    $upload_file = $upload_dir.$_FILES['file']['name'][$key];
    $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'][$key];
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$key],$upload_file)){
        //Here, Insert the path or filename into database.
    }
}
```